# APEX Report printing with BI Publisher Error. ORA-22973: HTTP request failed ORA-06512:at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1324 ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

Tags: oracle, report, oracle-apex, bi-publisher

I have Installed Oracle APEX 18.1 on oracle database 11g. Now I install oracle BI Publisher using complete OBIEE 11.1.1. I have given exact entries in instance setting at instance management in APEX for BI Publisher as mentioned in many forums. When I generate a report using generic layout and hit on test report button it gives me following error.
APEX Report printing with BI Publisher Error. ORA-22973: HTTP request failed ORA-06512:at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1324 ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact
And if I gave a proper rtf format as per my report query it generates a pdf file which cant be open because of incorrect format.
I have made correct entries in ACL as available on many websites.
Kindly brief about any missing step.

I have followed [this document](https://mostafizmitul.wordpress.com/2018/08/26/oracle-apex-18c-n-bi-publisher-integration/) mainly for guidance.